# How to make new command work in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, insert

I have a gridview, in the gridview task, I choose Edit Column-> Selected Fields->Command Field.select insert button to True. And the New link field appear, and I check the HTML Source,
look like necessary codes are there, but when I click on the "New" link field, no response at all, but update is ok for me, delete I have not tested yet.

Below are codes for the gridview and sqldatasource :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="agreement_no,id" Font-Size="9pt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="agreement_no" HeaderText="agreement_no" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="agreement_no"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="status" DataValueField="status" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("status") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GPGConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [status] FROM [deal_master]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sales_person" HeaderText="sales_person" SortExpression="sales_person"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="swap_carrier" HeaderText="swap_carrier" SortExpression="swap_carrier"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="start_pos" HeaderText="start_pos" SortExpression="start_pos"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="end_pos" HeaderText="end_pos" SortExpression="end_pos"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="swap_commitment" HeaderText="swap_commitment" SortExpression="swap_commitment"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="zone" HeaderText="zone" SortExpression="zone"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="target_minutes" HeaderText="target_minutes" SortExpression="target_minutes"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="target_sell_rate" HeaderText="target_sell_rate" SortExpression="target_sell_rate"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="target_buy_rate" HeaderText="target_buy_rate" SortExpression="target_buy_rate"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" DataField="supplier_interconnect" HeaderText="supplier_interconnect" SortExpression="supplier_interconnect"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" DataField="customer_interconnect" HeaderText="customer_interconnect" SortExpression="customer_interconnect"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="target_sales" HeaderText="target_sales" SortExpression="target_sales"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="target_cost" HeaderText="target_cost" SortExpression="target_cost"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="target_profit" HeaderText="target_profit" SortExpression="target_profit"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lcr_zone" HeaderText="lcr_zone" SortExpression="lcr_zone"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GPGConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [deal_master] WHERE [agreement_no] = @agreement_no AND [id] = @id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [deal_master] ([agreement_no], [status], [sales_person], [swap_carrier], [start_pos], [end_pos], [swap_commitment], [zone], [target_minutes], [target_sell_rate], [target_buy_rate], [supplier_interconnect], [customer_interconnect], [target_sales], [target_cost], [target_profit], [lcr_zone], [id]) VALUES (@agreement_no, @status, @sales_person, @swap_carrier, @start_pos, @end_pos, @swap_commitment, @zone, @target_minutes, @target_sell_rate, @target_buy_rate, @supplier_interconnect, @customer_interconnect, @target_sales, @target_cost, @target_profit, @lcr_zone, @id)" SelectCommand="SELECT [agreement_no], [status], [sales_person], [swap_carrier], [start_pos], [end_pos], [swap_commitment], [zone], [target_minutes], [target_sell_rate], [target_buy_rate], [supplier_interconnect], [customer_interconnect], [target_sales], [target_cost], [target_profit], [lcr_zone], [id] FROM [deal_master]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [deal_master] SET [status] = @status, [sales_person] = @sales_person, [swap_carrier] = @swap_carrier, [start_pos] = @start_pos, [end_pos] = @end_pos, [swap_commitment] = @swap_commitment, [zone] = @zone, [target_minutes] = @target_minutes, [target_sell_rate] = @target_sell_rate, [target_buy_rate] = @target_buy_rate, [supplier_interconnect] = @supplier_interconnect, [customer_interconnect] = @customer_interconnect, [target_sales] = @target_sales, [target_cost] = @target_cost, [target_profit] = @target_profit, [lcr_zone] = @lcr_zone WHERE [agreement_no] = @agreement_no AND [id] = @id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="agreement_no" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="agreement_no" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="sales_person" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="swap_carrier" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="start_pos" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="end_pos" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="swap_commitment" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="zone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_minutes" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_sell_rate" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_buy_rate" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="supplier_interconnect" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="customer_interconnect" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_sales" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_cost" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_profit" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="lcr_zone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="sales_person" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="swap_carrier" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="start_pos" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="end_pos" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="swap_commitment" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="zone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_minutes" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_sell_rate" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_buy_rate" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="supplier_interconnect" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="customer_interconnect" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_sales" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_cost" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="target_profit" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="lcr_zone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="agreement_no" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GPGConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [agreement_no] FROM [deal_master] ORDER BY [agreement_no]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
<br />
<div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0zrp.png)
my question is : what is the actions or setting I missed?
I want to know what steps I missed?
My objective is : I want to click on the "New" linkfield then 1 empty row appear, then I input the value in the new created row and I can save it or cancel it

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for the GridView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview), it says:

> Inserting records into the data source is not directly supported by the GridView control. However, it is possible to insert records by using the GridView control in conjunction with the DetailsView or FormView control. For more information, see DetailsView or FormView, respectively.

Additionally, the [CommandField documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.showinsertbutton) states about the ShowInsertButton property:

> This property applies only to data-bound controls that support insert operations, such as the DetailsView control.

So, you'll need to create your own form separately, or leverage a DetailsView or FormView. Or better yet: ditch Web Forms altogether if you can, as it's a dead platform, as I explain [on my blog](https://masonmcg.com/Blog/entry/stop-using-aspnet-webforms).